# How to plot line from point to point in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

how could I plot x axis (graph withnout y axis) with various color lines connectig intervals?

For example:
First line I want to go from point (1,8) to (6,8) - first color
The second: from (12,8) to (40,8) - second color
The third: form (50,8) to (56,8) and (60,8) to (74,8) - third color

I tried this as sorce file

```
56278.5545, 52676,5737
56300.5016, 55833,2969
```

and commands

```
plot 'pokryti.txt' using 1:0 with lines, '' using 2:0 with lines
```

but there is not constant for y value.

Or I tried to add trird column with sames values and

```
plot 'pokryti.txt' using 1:3 with lines, '' using 2:3 with lines
```

but nothing was plotted.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far and can share with us?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: Two hints for further clarification of what you want:  Make sure that your data file is consistent - are you separating columns by comma or by whitespace? Your data sample is inconclusive. And you might be more specific with your description of your desired outcome. `gnuplot` actually produces a graph with your data and command, but is it what you want?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I corrected mistakes and it works.